# Android Button and Variable

Tags: android, button, logging

I have a few buttons and I want to log the ID of the pressed button and undo it's action?

This is one of my buttons:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btn1:
      // More code here...
      btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
break;
   case R.id.btn2:
   // More buttons...
```

I'm trying to get the last pressed button's ID and make it visible again when pressing an "UNDO" button.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: in above code btn1 can not be made visible with button1 itself you need to redesign your app. Alternately you can change the color of button to match the background color and remove its text

Comment: I failed to explain the situation correctly, please see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to toggle the visibility of the clicked view, there is no need for all that code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   boolean vis = v.getVisibility();
   v.setVisibility(!vis);
}
```

Ok... To answer your updated question.

1) Create a class level variable.

```
private int mLastClickedId = -1;
```

2) In your undo-able buttons onClick store the Id of the clicked view into your variable.

```
Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Store the clicked view's Id
    mLastClickedId = v.getId();
}
```

3) In your undo button's onClick.

```
Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Fisrt make sure one of the undo-able buttons has been clicked.
    if (mLastClickedId != -1) {

        // Get the last clicked view
        View targetView = (View)findViewById(mLastClickedId);

        // Set its visibility
        targetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

This provides a simple single undo. It could easily be modified using an array to store a history of clicked Ids.

Comment: Thanks, I would still like to know how to get the last pressed button and call and "undo" button

Comment: Ah, it makes perfect sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Just updated my code example again, because you'll want to check 'mLastClickedId' has actually been set before trying to call 'findViewById()'.